# Plot lat and lon grid on a world map using Matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, latitude-longitude

Can anyone help me how to plot latitude and longitude on a world map using matlab. I have the mapping toolbox and have been trying to use the function geoshow, however I can´t get it right. I plot the world map using plot_google_map:

```
plot(lon,lat,'.k','MarkerSize',6)
hold on 
plot_google_map('maptype','roadmap')
```

This is the figure I get:

[image]

However I am not able to get the latitude and longitude grid on this picture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this going to help, but try reversing the order of your `plot` statements - its possibly that the map plot may be overwriting all the data of the `lon` and `lat` data.

Alternatively, if the function allows for it, plot the map as the back layer.